# Found unexpected behaviour of find() method of Matcher in java

Tags: java

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String country="india";
        String arry[]={"indians are great","i am india","govt","dhoomindian","prashindiahim","i jdsdindi a","i n d i a"};
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*" + country + ".*");
        for (String stringVal : arry) 
        {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(stringVal);
            System.out.println("test1..."+" -->"+stringVal+"  "+m.find());
            System.out.println("test2..."+" -->"+stringVal+"  "+m.find());
        }
    }
}


OUTPUT::

*test1... -->indians are great  true*   ----1
**test2... -->indians are great  false**-----2
*test1... -->i am india  true*   ----3
**test2... -->i am india  false** ---4
test1... -->govt  false
test2... -->govt  false
test1... -->dhoomindian  true----5
test2... -->dhoomindian  false----6
test1... -->prashindiahim  true----7
test2... -->prashindiahim  false----8
test1... -->i jdsdindi a  false
test2... -->i jdsdindi a  false
test1... -->i n d i a  false
test2... -->i n d i a  false
```

you can see the same find() method gives true in first line and false in the preceded second line.you can see the behaviour from line 1-8.
can any one tell me why i got this behaviour of find() method.

Comment: There's nothing unexpected here, it's explained in the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--).

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())

> public boolean find()
>   Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.
>   This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, **if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match**.

Comment: So if you pass in `indiaindiaindia`, `find()` will return `true` three times before reaching the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The `find()` method will search for the specific pattern and returns true if it finds it, HOWEVER, if you call `find()` again, it continues to search **FROM THAT POINT ONWARD** in that String. There, you get false bcz it can't find it.

If you use `find(int location)` you can tell it where in the string to search for, thereby allowing you to find the same pattern as many times as you like.

Comment: thanx for yours suggestion @blahfunk,@nateyolles,@biziclop